# How get default namespace of project with roslyn?

Tags: c#, namespaces, roslyn

I have an c# project. I have renamed NameSpaceDeclarationSyntax for example namespace1 to namespace2 .
When I compiled this project with visual studio and roslyn api I find out that visual studio has embedded the all resources of project with namespace2 just the resources file in properties folder has embedded with default namespace of project.

I have embedded all resources with namespace2 with roslyn  and because of this it doesn't run .

the following exception had thrown :

> Couldn't find any resources appropriate for specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure namespace1.properties.Resources.resources was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "assemblyname" ...

I must change the default namespace of project or get the default namespace and embed with that but I don't know how find or change default namespace of project ?

Comment: I couldn't find anything, you might consider asking at [the roslyn repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default namespace is a property of MSBuild and Visual Studio, not the compilers themselves.  Therefore, you won't find it in the Roslyn API.

Instead, you can change the `<RootNamespace>` element directly in the project file.

You can see how Roslyn's Visual Studio layers get the default namespace [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/afd10305a37c0ffb2cfb2c2d8446154c68cfa87a/src/VisualStudio/Core/Def/Implementation/ProjectSystem/VisualStudioProjectManagementService.cs#L32).

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

To get the default namespace you can use code below:

```cs
context.Options.AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider.GlobalOptions.TryGetValue(MatchFolderAndNamespaceConstants.RootNamespaceOption, out var rootNamespace);
```

Like used in the `AbstractMatchFolderAndNamespaceDiagnosticAnalyzer.cs` Roslyn analyzers repo [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/d7f5e615c6b66792b332a56cd655045fd15fea45/src/Analyzers/Core/Analyzers/MatchFolderAndNamespace/AbstractMatchFolderAndNamespaceDiagnosticAnalyzer.cs#L61).

`MatchFolderAndNamespaceConstants` class you can find [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/d7f5e615c6b66792b332a56cd655045fd15fea45/src/Analyzers/Core/Analyzers/MatchFolderAndNamespace/MatchFolderAndNamespaceConstants.cs).

Here is my simple analyzer example:

```cs
public class MatchProjectAndNamespaceAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics
        => ImmutableArray.Create(Rules.MatchProjectAndNamespaceAnalyzerRule);

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.Analyze | GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.ReportDiagnostics);
        context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
        context.RegisterSyntaxTreeAction(AnalyzeSyntaxTree);
    }

    private void AnalyzeSyntaxTree(SyntaxTreeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var root = context.Tree.GetRoot(context.CancellationToken);
        var namespaceDeclarations = root.DescendantNodesAndSelf().OfType<BaseNamespaceDeclarationSyntax>();
        context.Options.AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider.GlobalOptions.TryGetValue(
            MatchFolderAndNamespaceConstants.RootNamespaceOption, out var rootNamespace);

        foreach (var namespaceDeclaration in namespaceDeclarations)
        {
            if (namespaceDeclaration.Name.ToString() != rootNamespace)
            {
                var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(
                    Rules.MatchProjectAndNamespaceAnalyzerRule,
                    namespaceDeclaration.Name.GetLocation(),
                    rootNamespace);

                context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
            }
        }
    }
}
```